# running function based on input field id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to put together a small function to change the class of a form's input field. I know that I can do this for a specific if but I would like the function to run for multiple fields using the appropriate id. My Javascript experience is limited and so is my jQuery. I am already using jQuery on the page for a dropdown/hamburger menu so would like to use jQuery for this. I would also want to use onChange rather than something like onKeyUp to trigger it as someone might paste with a mouse and I already have a focus class so only need to change the class when someone leaves the field.

What I have so far:

```
function fieldClass(id) {
    $('id').removeClass('err').addClass('wider');     
}

<input class="err" type="Text" name="eName" id="eName" maxlength="100" placeholder="Please provide a name for the event" onChange="fieldClass(this.id);">
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the function to run for multiple fields

Do like this, where you target a group of input's with a i.e. shared class, and with this you attached the handler direct to each input and does not need to mess around with id's, simpler and way more efficient code

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {   /* executes after page been loaded */

  $(".myinputs").change(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('err').addClass('wider');
  });

});
```

HTML

```
<input class="myinputs err" type="Text" name="eName" id="eName" maxlength="100" placeholder="Please provide a name for the event">
<input class="myinputs err" type="Text" name="eAddress" id="eAddress" maxlength="100" placeholder="Please provide an address for the event">
```

Comment: The elegance and simplicity of this method is how I like to code. I also just used the err class rather than adding the myinputs one as well. Thanks!

Comment: I am still having a problem making this code work. Could the version of jQuery be an issue? I am using jquery-3.1.1.min.js

Comment: @LarryMoss Then please post the code you have (preferable as a fiddle) and I'll have a look ... and btw, make sure it runs after page been loaded (made an update of my answer to show how)

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't think of the .ready function, that was all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#'+id)` instead of `$('id')` ! When you use `$('id')` js search for a tag named `<id>` !

```
<input class="err" type="Text" name="eName" id="eName" maxlength="100" placeholder="Please provide a name for the event" onChange="fieldClass(this.id);">
<script>
function fieldClass(id) {
    $('#'+id).removeClass('err').addClass('wider');     
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `fieldClass` function accepts an `id` parameter but you are not using it. Instead, you used `'id'` as a string. Also, ID selectors should begin with a `#`. You should change it to:

```
$('#' + id).removeClass('err').addClass('wider');
```